# Financial API that provides Options Chains?

Tags: software-development, api, finance

Is there a Financial API (for use in software development with a programming language such as Java, Python, or .NET) that provides Options Chains?

I understand Yahoo had such an API and it was terminated in 2017. Does a replacement exist, even if it is not free?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [tradier.com](https://tradier.com/products/market-data-api).  I haven't used them in a while so I'm not sure how their services have changed but their api used to support getting option chains for various expiration dates.

Answer (score 0):

[TD Ameritrade's API](https://developer.tdameritrade.com/apis) provides option chains in real time.  See https://developer.tdameritrade.com/option-chains/apis/get/marketdata/chains for more info, and see https://pastebin.com/nxGFc3ef for an example of an option chain that I recently downloaded using the API.